# VBox Failed to open/create the internal network after upgrading to ubuntu 13.10

Tags: virtualbox, 13.10, virtualbox-networking

Every thing was perfect I have 2 guest Virtual machines (ubuntu server 12.04 and Win 7) on ubuntu 13.04 **but after upgrading host to 13.10 I can't start them** with bridged network adaptator....

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-wlan0' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network 
LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

---

Código Resultado: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Componente: Console

### Interfaz: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}

Vbox 4.2.12

May you help me ?

[image: Vbox message error]

[image: Vbox network configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with VirtualBox 4.2 and newer kernels. You could install 4.3 from the .deb or by adding their repo from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads .

Comment: No 13.10 package available yet...

Comment: 13.04 package work fine, thank you

Answer (score 10):

Try loading the kernel module (network filter driver) manually :

```
sudo modprobe vboxnetflt
```

Comment: In my case I was getting a Exec format error so I had to use: sudo modprobe --verbose --force-vermagic vboxnetflt

Comment: I am in Vbox 6.1 and this was the final answer numerous steps before this, but Virtualbox gave me those answer, it was this final answer that Virtualbox was not providing.

Comment: Issue only happened for me because I was trying to bridge my ethernet interface (not wifi)