# where can I find the official virtual box for ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-xp

where can I find the official virtual box for ubuntu 13.10?

I would like to run windows XP on it as the application I want to run needs .net 2.0

Comment: As per today Oracle Virtual Box do not yet provide a Saucy build. You will have to wait until its there or compile yourself.

Comment: According to [this thread in the virtualbox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=57891) you can try to install the 13.04 (raring) version which may also run in 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download the latest version 4.3.0, just as Babin said in his answer, you can download it from the [VirtualBox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).  Make sure you download the right file for your architecture (32bit or 64bit).  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded, probably the downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

If you don't mind verison 4.2.16, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Answer (score 1):

At https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

-->> Ubuntu 13.04 ("Raring Ringtail")  i386 |  AMD64 **Works Fine** with 13.10

Ubuntu 12.10 ("Quantal Quetzal")  i386 |  AMD64 Doesn't, [had some networks configuration problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360729/vbox-failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10/360947?noredirect=1#360947) in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Install the dependency packages:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Add the Oracle PPA and public key:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

[Add the VirtualBox repo](http://namhuy.net/2077/how-to-install-virtualbox-virtual-machine-on-ubuntu-fedora.html) on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander and Linux Mint 16 Petra:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list'
```

Install VirtualBox on Ubuntu and Linux Mint:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and thanks for contributing. Your answer seems to be valid, but what is the talk about Mint?

Answer (score 0):

Here u can Download the latest Virtualbox

[Virtual Box official Download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Are u can get it from the Ubuntu software center too

Instead of using Virtual box use KVM its better than virtual box and good in speed